# Checking is StringBuilder() AppendLine() is an empty string

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, append, stringbuilder

I want to conditionally append a string, derived from a function, to a string builder. The required condition is that the function is not returning a blank string ("").

The purpose of conditionally appending the string is to avoid `AppendLine()` appending a line when the string (returned from the function) being appended is empty.

**My current code (wrapping the function in a condition calling the very same function):**

```
Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

builder.Append("Some text...").AppendLine()

If Not IsNothing(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB)) Then
    builder.Append(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB)).AppendLine()
End If

If Not IsNothing(someFunction(someParameterBA, someParameterBB)) Then
    builder.Append(someFunction(someParameterBA, someParameterBB)).AppendLine()
End If
builder.AppendLine().Append("...some text.")

Dim s As String = builder.ToString
MessageBox.Show(s)
```

It is my hope that a more efficient alternative exists (efficient in terms of the amount of code to be written). Ultimately, I'd like to avoid calling the same function twice however I cannot independently add the `builder.Append` line of code to my function. Is it instead possible to target `builder.Append`?

Example of the potential logic:

```
If `builder.Append()` inside the following brackets is not an empty string then:
(
builder.Append(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB)).AppendLine()
)
```

If anyone has a solution on the above, bear in mind the prequisite of concision (=< 2) lines of code additional to the `builder.Append()` line.

I'm open to any other suggestions.

Comment: You know that you can use variables to store method return values? I'm just asking...

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, that's news to me. Researching examples now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you're referring to defining `someVariable = someFunction()` then yes, apologies, I'm aware of this approach and indeed, using the variable rather than the function reads (and  probably executes) better. Admittedly, it didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another method to do the appending like so:

```
CheckBeforeAppend(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB), builder)
CheckBeforeAppend(someFunction(someParameterBA, someParameterBB), builder)
....
Public Sub CheckBeforeAppend(s As String, sb As StringBuilder)

  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    sb.Append(s).AppendLine()
  End If

End Sub
```

A simple refactor such as this shortens your original code and means you don't need to duplicate the null or empty check on the return value of your function.

And for the extension method (place this code in a `Module`):

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub CheckBeforeAppend(s As String, sb As StringBuilder)

  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    sb.Append(s).AppendLine()
  End If

End Sub
```

usage:

```
someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB).CheckBeforeAppend(sb)
```

or for an extension on `StringBuilder`:

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub CheckBeforeAppend(sb As StringBuilder, s As String)

  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    sb.Append(s).AppendLine()
  End If

End Sub
```

usage:

`builder.CheckBeforeAppend(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to successfully integrate your solution into my working code. I really like how it streamlines what I was trying to achieve into a single line of code and relegates the rest to a method. I had tried and failed to call `AppendLine()` from a method in earlier attempts. I didn't realise I could set `StringBuilder` as a parameter data-type. Very happy with this neat solution. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better with an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

Comment: Glad it helped. Parameter datatypes can be any reference or value type, doing things like this, as you said, streamlines code and makes it more readable/maintainable

Comment: I appreciate the coded Extension Method example. I can confirm that that it successfully works with my actual code. Two minor nuances my version of Visual Studio required of me: 1) Writing `StringBuilder` as `System.Text.StringBuilder` and 2) Adding `Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices` before my module. Though these nuances may be unique to my end, they may be worth the mention for future readers.

Comment: the import statement for `CompilerServices` is needed for the `<Extension()`> attribute. You could also add the following import statement: `Imports System.Text` instead of fully qualifying the `StringBuilder` parameter

Comment: Fine, but I was thinking about an extension method for the StringBuilder class not for the string class. Something like `sb.CheckBeforeAppend(someFunctionThatReturnAString(p1,p2))` and AppendLine has an overload that takes a string, the two calls are not needed

Comment: shouldn't be a problem. swap the parameters around and it should still work the same, just use it on a `StringBuilder` instance instead!

Comment: @Steve The how and less importantly for now, the why of your last recommendation completely evades me. Using your code line, I substituted in the function that will produce the string. I receive an error stating `'CheckBeforeAppend' is not a member of 'System.Text.StringBuilder'`. Any further context on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm also uncertain where the overload you've referred to is occurring. Are you suggesting that I remove `AppendLine()` and use `vbNewLine` in the string for `Append()` instead?

Comment: instead of using `Append("some text")`, use `AppendLine("some text")`. this basically does what you're doing now with the `Append().AppendLine()` @ClarusDignus: swap the parameters around in the extension method so that you can use `CheckBeforeAppend` on a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Hi Ric. I'm not having an luck rearranging the extension for `StringBuilder`. I tried swapping the positioning of the functions assuming that this would determine `someFunction()` as the extension instead `CheckBeforeAppend` but either way, I'm being told `'CheckBeforeAppend' is not a member of 'System.Text.StringBuilder'`. Can you expand in layman's terms what you mean by swapping the parameters around?

Comment: I had begun typing my last comment before I read your penultimate comment. I can confirm that this works on my end. Thanks for your promptness/patience. Very finally, can either yourself or Steve briefly explain why the Extension Method is superior in this case and/or why it's superior to use the Extension Method for the StringBuilder class instead of the string class? Is it a matter of readability? i.e. `builder.CheckBeforeAppend(someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB))` looks/reads consistent with `builder.AppendLine("Some text...")` or is it a matter of superior functionality?

Comment: @ClarusDignus it is not a matter of superiority in terms of perfomance of other measurable parameter. The point is: The StringBuilder class has the responsability of creating and internally maintaining your string buffer so it appears natural that is this object that append data in a checked manner to its buffer. However remember that Extension Methods are just syntax sugar, they are in all aspects simple functions that the compiler  allow you to call in a more 'object oriented way' without requiring to derive a new class from the original one.

Comment: @Steve Logic for using StringBuilder class understood. Explanation of use of Extension Methods for prettier syntax and an object oriented feel understood. Thanks to yourself and Ricki for helping me produce a sleek line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid calling the function twice by storing the result of the function in a variable.

```
Dim myString As String = someFunction(someParameterAA, someParameterAB)
If myString <> "" Then
    builder.Append(myString).AppendLine()
End If

myString = someFunction(someParameterBA, someParameterBB)
If myString <> "" Then
    builder.Append(myString).AppendLine()
End If
```

This way you just call the function once and check your conditions with the variable. Also the code looks a lot smaller and more understandable.

Comment: +1 for illustrating how to define function's returned value as a variable. Though your answer is correct and indeed streamlines my code, Ric's answer goes a few steps further in streamlining my code by reducing multiple if null/empty conditions to the one method.